# IndexError: list index out of range i have a specific Local Outlier factor problem

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, outliers, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in

----> 3 df[ii] = pd.read_csv('/content/CSVs/' + x[ii]).dropna()

```
ii = 0

df[ii] = pd.read_csv('/content/CSVs/' + x[ii]).dropna()
rf[ii] = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
rf[ii].fit(  df[ii].select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).replace((np.inf, - 
np.inf, np.nan), 0) ,df[ii][' Label'])

f_i[ii] = list(zip(df[ii].columns,rf[ii].feature_importances_))
f_i[ii].sort(key = lambda x : x[1])
plt.barh([x[0] for x in f_i[ii][-20:]],[x[1] for x in f_i[ii][-20:]])
plt.show()
```

IndexError: list index out of range

This is the code, can someone please help me with this

Comment: What is `x`, is it a list, and does it contain anything?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.